# Is this overloading?

Tags: c++, overloading, return-type, overload-resolution, function-declaration

If I have two functions like this:

```
int f ( int a )
{}

void f ( signed a )
{}
```

are they overloaded?

When in `main()` I call `f(5)`, I get an error:

```
old declaration ‘void f(int)’
```

Comment: you don't really need to call them btw.

Comment: _"Are the functions here overloaded ?"_ No, these are using the same parameter type effectively.

Comment: Don't describe the code that's producing your error.  Show the actual code.

Comment: `int` and `signed` are the same type. You can't overload a function based on its return type alone, because the compiler needs to be able to determine which overload to call based on the arguments provided.

Comment: @ Nathan Yes that is a point I know the concept of overloading but don't know that type signed and int is the same .

Comment: @User it's a holdover from `C` "everything" was `int` if you left out some of the type declaration.

Comment: Where can I find the reference of different and same data type . I searched but couldn't find a reference for them . Thanks a lot

Comment: @User Fundamental Types https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types  Page down to the table in __Integer types__

Comment: @Richard thanks . But excuse me what do you mean by everything" was int if you left out some of the type declaration

Comment: @User it not something you want to remember (or even learn) but in old `C` you could just call a function (without declaring it) and the compiler would assume it was of the form `int fun(int)` also `signed` is `signed int`; `short` is `short int` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type specifiers `signed` and `int` (used alone without other type specifiers) define the same signed integer type.

That is you may equivalently write for example

```
int a;
signed a;
signed int a;
int signed a;
```

So the functions in the question have the same parameter declaration.

However they have different return types

```
int f ( int a )
{ }

void f ( signed a)
{}
```

That is the same function is redefined with different return types. The return type does not take part in function overloading.

So the compiler issues an error that the same function is defined twice with different return types.

From the C++ 14 Standard (13.1 Overloadable declarations)

> 2 Certain function declarations cannot be overloaded:
>
> (2.1) — Function declarations that differ only in the return type
> cannot be overloaded

If you would change the parameter declaration in one of the functions for example the following way

```
int f ( int a )
{ }

void f ( unsigned a)
{}
```

then the functions would be overloaded and this statement

```
f( 5 );
```

would call the first overloaded function because the integer literal `5` has the type `int`..